# What is the best way to configure email in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I am currently doing a project using Codeigniter. The application **sends mail on different purpose**. Currently, I have this code in my Model. What I want to know how can I reuse or what is the best way to reuse this code without reinitializing the email settings.

```
        $subject = 'Password Reset';
        $email['userinfo']=trim(ucwords($input['email'])); //user's email
        $app_email = 'myemail@domain.com';
        $app_password = 'password';
        $message = $this->load->view('forgot_mail',$email,TRUE); //message content

        /* CONFIGURE EMAIL SETTINGS */
        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.mail.domain.com';
        $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
        $config['smtp_user'] = $app_email;
        $config['smtp_pass'] = $app_password;
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->initialize($config);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `config` file named as  `mail.php`(or `email.php`) in `application/config/`.Then manage your setting in configuration file like this..

```
$config['useragent'] = 'CodeIgniter';
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'YOUREMAILHERE@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'YOURPASSWORDHERE';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465; 
$config['smtp_timeout'] = 5;
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['wrapchars'] = 76;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['validate'] = FALSE;
$config['priority'] = 3;
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['bcc_batch_mode'] = FALSE;
$config['bcc_batch_size'] = 200;
```

You can set only required config items.

Then in your `Controller`.

Load email library:

```
$this->load->library('email');
```

And set your mail message with subject,message,to,from etc...

```
    $subject = 'Password Reset';
    $email['userinfo']=trim(ucwords($input['email'])); //user's email
    $app_email = 'myemail@domain.com';
    $app_password = 'password';
    ...........//more
```

Working fine here.

Hope it works.

Comment: how to load email.php config file?

Comment: is this correct way
 $config = $this->config->load('email');
            $this->email->initialize($config);

Comment: Yes, you can separate you config file into application/config.php